# How Can I use initSelection in select 4.0.0

Tags: angularjs, select, coffeescript

I am using select 4.0.0 in a modal boopstrap, and I dont get load the data that I have selected. My code:

```
<select style="width:100%" class="configServices" multiple="true" ng-model="widget.configuration.services">
<optgroup ng-repeat="service in services" ng-if="service.children" label="{{service.service_name}}">
    <option ng-repeat="children in service.children" value="{{children.service_code}}">{{children.service_name}}</option>
</optgroup>>
<option ng-repeat="service in services" ng-if="!service.children" value="{{service.service_code}}">{{service.service_name}}</option>
```

My angularJS:

```
$scope.services = []
  $scope.images = []
  $scope.stringVal = []
  Services.status2 (services) ->
    services.data.forEach (service) ->
      $scope.services.push service
      if service.children
        service.children.forEach (children) ->
          $scope.images[children.service_name] = children.service_icon
      else $scope.images[service.service_name] = service.service_icon

  formatService = (service) ->
    return  $('<img style="height: 20px; width: 20px; border-radius:19px;" src="' +$scope.images[service.text]+ '" /><b>'+' '+service.text+'</b>')


  $(".configServices").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 15,
    templateResult: formatService,
    templateSelection: formatService
  });
```

How can I initialize the data that I have saved when I run the modal.